# Make an ajax call using form:select in spring mvc

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-mvc

I want to update a form:select where another form:select get changed using AJAX

```
<form:select id="villeID" path="ville.id">
   <option value="" disabled selected>
       Choisissez une Ville
   </option>
   <form:options items="${villeList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="libelle_ville" />
</form:select>
<form:select id="wilayaID" path="">
     <option value="" disabled selected>
         Choisissez une wilaya
     </option>
     <form:options items="${wilayaList}" itemValue="id_wilaya" itemLabel="libelle_willaya" />
</form:select>
```

And my controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addemployee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addEmployee(ModelMap model) {
    System.out.println("/addemployee");
    model.addAttribute("villeList", villeDAO.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("wilayaList", willayaDAO.findAll())
    model.addAttribute("newEmployee", new Employee());
    return "addemployee";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. it consisit to populate the second `form:select`  in the `callback` of the `Ajax` method